# Name Binding(Jersey) in DropWizard

Tags: java, rest, jersey, dropwizard

I want to create custom annotation with NameBinding of Jersey for Auth via JWT, I used this tech in another plain-java project and everything works perfect, but it's not working in DropWizard project. As I know DW also use Jersey for REST. this is my test code, but it's not working.

**Interface:**

```
@NameBinding
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({TYPE, METHOD})
public @interface Auth {}
```

**Implementation:**

```
@Auth
@Provider
public class AuthFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    private static final String SECRET = "SOME_SECRET_STRING";

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        try {
            String userToken = requestContext.getHeaderString("token");
            Claims body = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(SECRET).parseClaimsJws(userToken).getBody();
            if(body.getExpiration().before(new Date())) {
                requestContext.abortWith(Response
                        .status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED)
                        .entity("Token is expired")
                        .build());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            requestContext.abortWith(Response
                    .status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED)
                    .entity("Error")
                    .build());
        }
    }
}
```

**Rest:**

```
@GET
@Path("/test")
@Auth
public String test() {
    return "Hello, " + userName;
}
```

can anybody help with this issue?

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution and post the answer it would be helpful for somebody. I had to register the AuthFilter class in run method:

```
environment.jersey().register(new AuthFilter());
```